# How do i update a dataGridView on a Main Form after closing down an opened form

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I am slightly confused and baffled by refreshing a dataGridView once i have updated a table row and closed a form down.

I have 2 forms. `MainForm` and `EditAdminForm`. The main form contains the dataGridView which lists the table Admin. `EditAdminForm` is populated by a selected row of data from the dataGridView. Once updated i close down the form but the table does not fresh.

I have tried a simple `dataGridView.Refresh();` but this does not work.

***MainForm***

```
private void EditAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    EditAdminForm Admin = new EditAdminForm();

    Admin.idTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Admin.usernameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Admin.firstnameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    Admin.surnameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Admin.emailTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    Admin.statusCombo.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    Admin.ShowDialog();

}
```

***EditAdminForm***

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SQL Connection and SQL for updating admin information
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter sda3 = new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE Admin set Admin_Username='" + this.usernameTxt.Text + "' , Admin_FName='" + this.firstnameTxt.Text + "' , Admin_SName='" + this.surnameTxt.Text + "' , Admin_Email='" + this.emailTxt.Text + "', Admin_Status='" + this.statusCombo.Text + "' WHERE Admin_ID='" + this.idTxt.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            sda3.Fill(dt3);
            MessageBox.Show("Information Successfully Updated!");
            dt3.Clear();

            this.Close();

        }
```

***Loading the table data***

```
public void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'student_CBDataSetStudent.Student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.student_CBDataSetStudent.Student);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'student_CBDataSetAdmin.Admin' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.adminTableAdapter.Fill(this.student_CBDataSetAdmin.Admin);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this including using data binding on the `EditAdminForm`, but the easiest way is probably just to update the row in the `SaveBtn_Click` method. Technically, it is more accurate to requery and repopulate the DataGridView although not always necessary. If the update succeeds then you can probably just update the data in the row directly by storing the row when you open `EditAdminForm`:

```
private void EditAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var admin = new EditAdminForm();
    admin.CurrentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
    admin.ShowDialog();
}

// EditAdminForm
private DataGridRow _currentRow;
public DataGridRow CurrentRow
{
    get { return _currentRow; }
    set
    {
        _currentRow = value;
        if (value == null)
        {
            // TODO: Clear form
        }
        else
        {
            usernameTxt.Text = value.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            firstnameTxt.Text = value.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            surnameTxt.Text = value.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            emailTxt.Text = value.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            statusCombo.Text = value.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateCurrentRow()
{
    if (_currentRow == null) return;
    _currentRow.Cells[0].Value = idTxt.Text;
    _currentRow.Cells[1].Value = usernameTxt.Text;
    _currentRow.Cells[2].Value = firstnameTxt.Text;
    _currentRow.Cells[3].Value = surnameTxt.Text;
    _currentRow.Cells[4].Value = emailTxt.Text;
    _currentRow.Cells[6].Value = statusCombo.Text;
}

private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save connection, same as before...
    // then update the row
    UpdateCurrentRow();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This Doesnt work. I get errors with using currentRow and Cells

Comment: You will need to provide more information, e.g. StackTrace and Exception, if you are looking for more help. Most likely it is something you will need to figure out that is specific to your program.

Answer (score 0):

In your edit admin table you edit stuff in your "database", not in your table. 
That means you have to reload the table when you're done.

Attach a handler to "Closed" event in your main form with instructions to refresh. This will trigger the update automatically when form is closed:

```
    private void EditAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        EditAdminForm Admin = new EditAdminForm();
        Admin.Closed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e){
           this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.student_CBDataSetStudent.Student);
           this.adminTableAdapter.Fill(this.student_CBDataSetAdmin.Admin);
        };
        Admin.idTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Admin.usernameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Admin.firstnameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        Admin.surnameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Admin.emailTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Admin.statusCombo.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

        Admin.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: im getting errors saying Error 1 A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: @DB just change to the following `+= delegate(object sender, EventArgs e2)`. There is already an `e` in the method, so you can't use it again in the lambda and you need a different name such as `e2`. Note, this will requery the students and admin and it will probably change the current row.

Comment: Its not even refreshing the datagridview